# Serial reading, only first 128 values taken into account

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, serial-port

I am reading a line from MCU via serial port. The line consists in 14 characters terminated by "OK". The characters are converted to int then processed. The problem is when the value becomes larger than 128. For values larger than 128 the value (int converted) remains at 63. Here is the code:

```
            serialPort1.DiscardInBuffer();
            serialPort1.DiscardOutBuffer();
            serialPort1.Write("d");//request line from mcu
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            string line = serialPort1.ReadLine();

            int p1_low = line[0];
            int p1_high = line[1]*256;
            int p1 = p1_low + (p1_high);
            label1.Text = "Input Sensor: " + p1_low;
```

p1_low varies much often than p1_high and sticks to 63 value when is larger than 128. Where can be the problem?

Comment: 63 is a magic number.  It is the ASCII code for '?'  Your MCU is sending a byte whose value is larger then 127.  It sure sounds like you are using the wrong method, ReadLine() should only be used to read text.  Read bytes by using the Read() method.  Or fix your MCU code to send text instead of bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the encoding to

```
    SerialPort1.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(28591)
```

The default encoding, as you have discovered, replaces byte values > 127 with a '?'.  Encoding 28591 preserves byte values greater than 127.

You do not need the thread sleep as .ReadLine blocks.

Comment: I was thinking that MCU needs time to process and send data.

Comment: It doesn't matter as long as you have the .ReadTimeout Property set to the default, which is infinite.  With this setting the ReadLine will block until it receives a line from the SerialPort.

Comment: This did solve my issue when deal with mpu6050 and Unity c#. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are set to use 7 data bits.  Change the data bits config value to 8, so you can get all 256 values.

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.databits.aspx

Comment: I looked at the settings, the serial port is set to receive 8 bits, then i saw the value 63, this is the default value for replacing parity damaged bytes. I am using another software and i'm reading correctly. The parity is set to none. Should i insert time between bytes (at the mcu)?

Comment: The problem is encoding, yes, i receive 7 bits, but because of the encoding. Now the problem is to set encoding to 8 bits. How to do that?

Comment: Oh, I see. Read bytes, not strings!  `ReadBytes`, not `ReadLine`

Comment: For instance i want to change the encoding to 8bits. How to do that? After that i will read with readbyte (wich reads only one byte and i don't know yet how to do that with termination).

Comment: If you know it's 14 characters, one byte each, just read 14 bytes?  Or is it not always 14 characters?

Comment: `ReadBytes` and specify you want to read 14 of them?  You may need to loop until all 14 are received

Comment: Or... Just use an encoding that preserves byte values > 127 as I have shown.

Comment: No, a string is for text.  You don't want text!

Comment: Thanks! I will dig for more info about reading just a byte when i can, now i have to move on with the project. Thanks again, guys!

Answer (score -1):

Use the method
Write(Byte[], int32, int32) because a byte is a numerical value --> (0-255) or (0x00-0xFF) or (b00000000-11111111). A char or a string can be encoded but not a byte.
Make sure to
NOT use Write(Char[], int32, int32)

Comment: The question is about _READING_ not _writing_ so this answer does not apply at all. The other answers, provided 8 years ago are correct, encoding needs to be taken into account when using `ReadLine()` even if the sending _MCU_ was writing specific _bytes_. The bytes are correct, hte code needs to interpret them.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29994844)